# HTML with XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, xml

i have xml file which contains lots of data. now i want to pick a price with some condition. i set a parameteres in javascript function but it is not giving desire result. i think it can be done through childnode but i didnot aware about that

**XML file**

```
<flights updated="2012-03-09T04:38:00.437" type="flights" ob_id="45792117" lastedit="2012-03-09T15:10:01" partner_id="63" activate_date="2012-02-15T00:00:00" page_id="9646" page_pk_id="12597" pos_pk_id="51565" pos="1" module_id="3" pos_name="Flights" product_type_id="4" product_type="flight" headline="Bali" destination="Bali" localised_destination="Denpasar" headline_no_html="Bali" price="199" deals_space_limited="0" deals_sold_out="0" qa_approved="1" tp_available="0" tp_weight="10" partner_eapid="0-25" partner_pid="25" publish_path="\\dubvappdaily01\daily_aus\data\psf\" partner_lang_id="3081"  FrTLAs="PER" ToTLAs="DPS" FrDate="2012-04-27T00:00:00" ToDate="2012-05-04T00:00:00" Airline="QZ"/>

<flights updated="2012-03-09T04:38:00.437" type="flights" ob_id="45792117" lastedit="2012-03-09T15:10:01" partner_id="63" activate_date="2012-02-15T00:00:00" page_id="9646" page_pk_id="12597" pos_pk_id="51565" pos="1" module_id="3" pos_name="Flights" product_type_id="4" product_type="flight" headline="Bali" destination="Bali" localised_destination="Denpasar" headline_no_html="Bali" price="199" deals_space_limited="0" deals_sold_out="0" qa_approved="1" tp_available="0" tp_weight="10" partner_eapid="0-25" partner_pid="25" publish_path="\\dubvappdaily01\daily_aus\data\psf\" partner_lang_id="3081"  FrTLAs="SYD" ToTLAs="DPS" FrDate="2012-04-27T00:00:00" ToDate="2012-05-04T00:00:00" Airline="QZ"/>
```

**HTML page**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function myXml(origin, destination ) {
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("flights");

      for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
          if (x[i].getAttribute('FrTLAs') == origin
           && x[i].getAttribute('destination') == destination) {
              alert(x[i].getAttribute('price'))
          }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="myXml('SYD','Bali')">click me</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u miss this??

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("flights.xml");
```

chk this page

```
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_attributes.asp
```

the example2 is very clear how to use this

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0].attributes;
   //here its would be getElementsByTagName("flights") in the loop
   //then .attributes on it
   // and then this
frtlas=x.getNamedItem("FrTLAs");
desti=x.getNamedItem("destination");

//and your code here
```

hope this helps